# How we can reduce wordpress page loading time?

Tags: performance

How we can reduce wordpress page loading time ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**LiteSpeed Cache**
(1,033total ratings)
All-in-one unbeatable acceleration & PageSpeed improvement: caching, image/CSS/JS optimization…
https://wordpress.org/plugins/litespeed-cache/

**Autoptimize**
(994total ratings)
Autoptimize speeds up your website by optimizing JS, CSS, images (incl. lazy-load), HTML and Google Fonts, asyncing JS, removing emoji cruft and more.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/

**other plugins:** https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Cache/